# *ngFor not display

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-forms

Hey I know this question comes up a lot but the normal fixes do not work.

This is my code

```
export class CourseReviewFormComponent implements OnInit { 
 form: FormGroup
 questionnaire: string[] = [];
 currentQuestionsValue: string[] = [];

 constructor(private serverData: ServerService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.onGetForm();   
   }

 onGetForm() {
   this.serverData.getData('questionnaire/Student Course Review')
     .subscribe(
        (response: Response) => {
         this.questionnaire = response.json();
         let key = Object.keys(this.questionnaire);
         for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
           this.currentQuestionsValue.push(this.questionnaire[key[i]].items)
         }
         console.log('current Questions Value', this.currentQuestionsValue);
         },
          (error) => console.log('Form Error', error)
         )
      }
    }
```

my template

```
 <form>
  <div *ngFor="let data of currentQuestionsValue">
    <strong> {{ data.sno }}). </strong>
    <span>{{ data.question}}</span>
    <div>
      <label *ngFor="let op of data.options; let i = index">
        <input type="radio" name="option" [value]="i">
        <span>{{ op }}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But the ngFor does not display any data:

In `console.log('current Value', this.currentValue);` works good.

But, when I run ngFor loop in DOM it does not work.
[image]

Comment: Looking at the console output, `currentQuestionsValue` is an array with only one element (which is also an array). That inner array is most likely the one you are looking for.

Comment: can you tell me now how I display in dom

Comment: Use `this.currentQuestionsValue = this.currentQuestionsValue[0]` It will do trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the first item of an array and iterate over its value which is also an array.

In the `ServerService` I would add intermediate steps to transform an observable like this:

```
.map(data => data.json())
.map(json => json[0])
```

Comment: @Adeel, For this answer Please look into this URL for more info. https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3

Comment: @Swanand raises a very good point. The article specified that you can either subscribe to a controller or in a view using the async pipe. I am a huge advocate of the second, however, didn't feel like it was part of the question.

Comment: @Swanand i tried but still not solve can you help me. i am so confuse in Observables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this.?

```
let data of currentQuestionsValue[0]
```